# how to get href from <a> when searching for text in beautiful soup and

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working with selenium and BeautifulSoup and Selenium to perform a data extract.

This page is paginated.  I know that this link exists somewhere on the page:

```
<a href="/DP/changeQueryPageAction.do?pager.offset=20">[ Next &gt; ]</a>
```

This url is in a random location on the page, so what I need to do is find the text and extract the href.

How do I ask bs4 to find the text, and give me the href?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find element based on text or any other attribute you have to use `re` module to get that.

```
import bs4
import re
html_doc="""<html><a href="/DP/changeQueryPageAction.do?pager.offset=20">[ Next &gt; ]</html></a>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
Search_Text=soup.find('a' , text=re.compile("Next"))
print(Search_Text['href'])
```

Output :

```
/DP/changeQueryPageAction.do?pager.offset=20
```

Please let me know if it works for you.